# Calling ajax() function, in .js file in /static/js

Tags: web2py

In order to make some of my code easier to reuse, I moved some javascript functions to [MyApp]/static/js/custom.js. One of the functions which was moved calls web2py's ajax() function, and the url which is passed to that function is generated with {{=URL(...)}} - under the new arrangement, the code which generates the url remains in the .html file, whereas the code that makes the ajax() call is in the separate .js file. The previous arrangement was this:

**view:**

```
<script>
   function generate_grid() {
     ...
     ajax("{{=URL('users','ajax_generate_grid')}}", [...], 'placeholder')
   }

   generate_grid()
</script>
```

That worked just fine. After moving the javascript code, the arrangement is as follows:

**[MyApp]/static/js/custom.js:**

```
function generate_grid(ajax_function_url) {
    ...
    ajax(ajax_function_url, [...], 'placeholder')
}
```

**view:**

```
<script>
   generate_grid("{{=URL('users','ajax_generate_grid')}}")
</script>
```

The new variant results in a rendering of the entire page (not just the newly-generated component) being inserted into the target div when the ajax call is made.

Is there a way to make sure that only the component generated by the ajax function is placed within the target div?

Comment: I don't think this change alone could result in this difference -- probably you changed something else as well. It sounds like in one case the action being called executes a view that extends the layout, and in the other case it does not. It's hard to say why without seeing the controller and view of the action being called. It would also help to know the extension of the containing page, as the `URL()` helper automatically propagates the current extension unless explicitly overridden (the extension determines which view is executed).

Comment: @Anthony - indeed, you were right - I screwed up something in the javascript when I moved the code, and the problem didn't result from any functionality intrinsic to web2py (I was initially messing around with the 'extension' and 'scheme' parameters of URL() to try to fix it, so your suggestion was very helpful in telling me where *not* to look). Thank you!